# Phase difference in superconducting ring and gradient theorem

Tags: superconductivity, vector-fields

In [Feymann's seminar on superconductivity](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_21.html#mjx-eqn-EqIII2118) there was this equation (21.28) $\oint_C\nabla \theta \cdot ds=\frac q \hbar\Phi$. Closed line integral $\oint_C\nabla \theta \cdot ds$ was claimed to be non-zero. However, since $\nabla\theta$ is a conservative field why doesn't this violate the gradient theorem $\int_\gamma \nabla \theta \cdot ds= \theta(a)-\theta(b)$ where $a$ is the start point and $b$ the finish point of the path, and in the case of a loop $a=b$.